# Copy text displayed on html page into text file

Tags: javascript, html

I am converting Jenkins Timestamp into Date format using moment.js within a html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Convert Jenkins TimeStamp to Date Format</title>
    <script src="moment.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="momenttd"></div>
<script>
var timestamp = 1528978234987;
var fmtdate = moment(timestamp).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
document.getElementById('momenttd').innerHTML = fmtdate;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

On launching the html file, it is giving me exactly the date as I need.
Next, I want to copy that displayed date into a text file, moment the page is lainched. Since, it is a local html file, file:///C:/date.html, neither wget nor curl is helping in fetching that displayed date.

Can anyone please help me, on how I can achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client machine browser will not allowed to write file without permission or by disabling some security option.

```js
var timestamp = 1528978234987;
var fmtdate = moment(timestamp).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
document.getElementById('momenttd').innerHTML = fmtdate;


window.onload = function () {
    var textFile = null,
        makeTextFile = function (text) {
            var data = new Blob([text], {
                type: 'text/plain'
            });

           
            if (textFile !== null) {
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
            }

            textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

            return textFile;
        };


    var create = document.getElementById('create'),
        momenttd = document.getElementById('momenttd').textContent;

    create.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
        link.href = makeTextFile(momenttd);
        link.style.display = 'block';
    }, false);
    document.getElementById("create").click();
    document.getElementById("downloadlink").click();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>


<div id="momenttd"></div>
<button id="create" style="display: none">Create file</button> <a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>
```

Hope this will helps you.